# jQuery catch when animation is finished

Tags: jquery, colors, background, animation

I'm using [color plugin](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:dpcapYz_QpUJ:plugins.jquery.com/project/color+http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color) (link to google cache, jquery.com currently off) to handle background color animations.

```
$(".navigation a").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor: black});
    },
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor: green});
        $(this).hide();
    }
);
```

**Need to hide current link when animation is finished.** Now it hides at once, on `mouseout()`.

**What is the solution?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put the `.hide()` into the callback function of the `.animate()` call.

```
$(this).stop().animate(
    {backgroundColor: green},
    function() {
        $(this).hide();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

By giving `.hide()` a duration, it will be added to the animation queue.

So you can do this:

```
$(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor: green}).hide( 0 );
```

Comment: +1 this works great with a "tweenable" animation (background-color isn't one, but that's not your fault).  Quite clever, really :-)

Comment: @Andy E - Thanks. :o) You can animate backgroundColor if you have jQueryUI. http://jsfiddle.net/mfJhH/ Was that what you meant by tweenable?

Comment: yeah, it was and I didn't know that.  It's pretty neat, thanks :-)

Comment: Oops - I gave the example of the other answer. Here's mine. http://jsfiddle.net/mfJhH/1/